# Swift Spritekit Background image

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've recently started learning swift and sprite kit. i am currently trying to do the basics and was trying to fit a background image on to the screen. i have managed to get the background picture up and in the centre of the screen but it is not filling up the whole screen. all help would be appreciated.

```
    import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        let bgImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background.png")
        bgImage.position = CGPoint(x:self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
        bgImage.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
        bgImage.zPosition = -1
        self.addChild(bgImage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the size of your sprite to fit the size the scene

```
bgImage.size = self.size
```

Of course if the proportions of the scene are different from the proportions of the sprite, the sprite will be stretched.

> Thank you to *@Knight0fDragon* for the helpful comments below.

Comment: thank you very much the picture has over stretched but at least its fitting the screen

Comment: Use the scene size, not the view size.  @harreskhan,  this may be happening because you have .AspectFill as your scale filter

Comment: Nope, using the scene size can stretch the sprite as well if the scene size has different proportions than the sprite size. Furthermore if the scene is much larger than the view you'll get the sprite to be oversized.

Comment: yes, but your scene size may not be your view size,  a background image for a scene should not be be filling based on the view, it should be filling based on the scene,  that is why I said use the scene size, not the view size

Comment: `a background image for a scene should not be be filling based on the view, it should be filling based on the scene`. I don't agree. It really depends on the game. Sometimes it can be true, sometimes can be false.

Comment: your scene area will never be larger than your view area,  the 4 modes you  have will now allow it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: Wrong. From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKScene/scaleMode):  `It is possible for a scene’s size to differ from the size of the view it is presented in. The scale mode determines how the visible portion of the scene is mapped to the view.`.

Comment: if your scene size is larger then your view size,  it will either scale or resize the view,  any scaling will cause your code to be be inaccurate, and resizing will yield the same result

Comment: That is why I said scene area

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean with `scene area`? Don't you mean the area of the scene?

Comment: if my scene is 20x20, and my view is 10x10, your code is now invalid in 3 scale modes, because it does not fill the entire scene anymore

Comment: The visible drawing area

Comment: Good point. If the scene is resized my solution does not work. I agree.

Comment: Working source code that shows how to dynamically resize the SpriteKit scene based on the view dimensions can be found in the SK2KTile github linked here: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post20_spritekit_repeat_shader